# How to "cd" to a directory after "grep"?

Tags: unix, terminal

I want to find a directory using `grep` then change current directory to the resulting directory.
For example:

```
$ ls | grep 1670 |
```

finds me directory haib12CJS1670. I am trying to do something like below:

```
$ ls | grep 1670 | cd
```

so that my directory is set to haib12CJS1670 at a single step. Obviously my way is not working. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Do you have a good reason to be using `grep` instead of globbing (i.e., `cd *1670*`?)

Comment: That is great comment for me, since I did not even know I could do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 cd `ls | grep 1670`
```

should get your `cd` to work (note, those are "back-ticks")

An alternative approach (some would say preferred) would be to use the `$` substitution. E.g.,

```
 cd $(ls | grep 1670)
```

though I can't get this to work with the `tcsh`, it works fine with `bash`.

The first solution is *shell-agnostic* :)

Comment: Wow, you are *lightning fast* Levon. Thank you!